# Access specific class implementation from static object

Tags: java, inheritance

Is it possible in java to get a specific implementation class while calling a method on a specific static object?

The thing i want to achive:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String testBase = TestEnum.TEST_BASE.getFields().TEST_STATICS_BASE_FIELD;
        String testExtension = TestEnum.TEST_EXTENSION.getFields().TEST_STATICS_EXTENSION_FIELD;    //this doesn't compile
    }

    public enum TestEnum {
        TEST_BASE(new TestStaticsBase()),
        TEST_EXTENSION(new TestStaticsExtension()),
        ;

        public TestStaticsBase fields;

        TestEnum(TestStaticsBase fields) {
            this.fields = fields;
        }

        public TestStaticsBase getFields() {
            return fields;
        }

        public static class TestStaticsBase {
            public final String TEST_STATICS_BASE_FIELD = "TEST_STATICS_BASE_FIELD";
        }

        public static class TestStaticsExtension extends TestStaticsBase {
            public final String TEST_STATICS_EXTENSION_FIELD = "TEST_STATICS_EXTENSION_FIELD";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i managed to resolve this problem by replacing enum with a generic class.

Solution:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String testBase = TestEnum.TEST_BASE.getFields().TEST_STATICS_BASE_FIELD;
        String testExtension = TestEnum.TEST_EXTENSION.getFields().TEST_STATICS_EXTENSION_FIELD;    //this doesn't compile
    }

    public static class TestEnum<T extends TestEnum.TestStaticsBase> {
        public static final TestEnum<TestEnum.TestStaticsBase> TEST_BASE = new TestEnum<>(new TestStaticsBase());
        public static final TestEnum<TestStaticsExtension> TEST_EXTENSION = new TestEnum<>(new TestStaticsExtension());
        ;

        public T fields;

        public TestEnum(T fields) {
            this.fields = fields;
        }

        public T getFields() {
            return fields;
        }

        public static class TestStaticsBase {
            public static final String TEST_STATICS_BASE_FIELD = "TEST_STATICS_BASE_FIELD";
        }

        public static class TestStaticsExtension extends TestStaticsBase {
            public static final String TEST_STATICS_EXTENSION_FIELD = "TEST_STATICS_EXTENSION_FIELD";
        }
    }
```

If this can be improved please let me know in comments

Comment: Ah that's nice, deleting my answer cause yours seems to be the one you were really looking for.

Comment: However, with implementation like this IDE suggests me to replace line `String testBase = TestEnum.TEST_BASE.getFields().TEST_STATICS_BASE_FIELD;` with `String testBase = TestEnum.TestStaticsBase.TEST_STATICS_BASE_FIELD;`. Is there any way to implement this so it won't suggest me this change?